# What does nearClipPlane and farClipPlane do when drawing a model?

Tags: c#, monogame

What does nearClipPlane and farClipPlane do when drawing a model in MonoGame?

I'm trying out 3D drawing using models made by a friend in Blender. I'm using some code I got off of an online tutorial to draw and it works fine. I am just curious what the nearClipPlane and farClipPlane variables do.

```
private void DrawModel()
{
    foreach (var mesh in Basilisk_MFT.Meshes)
    {
        foreach (BasicEffect basicEffect in mesh.Effects)
        {
            basicEffect.EnableDefaultLighting();
            basicEffect.PreferPerPixelLighting = true;
            basicEffect.World = Matrix.Identity;
            var cameraUpVector = Vector3.UnitZ;
            basicEffect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(cameraPosition, cameraLookAtVector, cameraUpVector);
            float aspectRatio = graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / (float)graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight;
            float fieldOfView = MathHelper.PiOver4;
            float nearClipPlane = 1;
            float farClipPlane = 200;
            basicEffect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(fieldOfView, aspectRatio, nearClipPlane, farClipPlane);
        }

        mesh.Draw();
    }
}
```

I assumed it was the minimum and maximum length for the 3D space or something, but I wasn't sure after adjusting the values.

Comment: These variables control models to render. Only models between nearClipPlane and farClipPlane will be rendered. If I remember it right.

Comment: So like bounds and whatever is inside them will be rendered?

Comment: Yeah. It should be this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The near/far pane defines the range of the zbuffer (which is in 0-1 range)

The geometry and pixels will be "rendered" in hardware anyway - but the pixel will be discarded, because it's outside the zbuffer range (I don't know if it's technically solved like that in hardware)

Another problem with a too big "distance" is Z-Fighting. The more distance has to be covered withing the 0-1 range of the zbuffer, the smaller the difference is between them (in 0-1 range) and therefore the floating point precision can result in z-Fighting (Flickering in very near pixels, they will "fight" for their z-value)